# Filling a Microsoft word document with Mail merge

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, ms-office

I have a field in the template I want to fill programatically, but the field was not found when I tried to debug. The field count returns 0. This is my code.

```
var application = new Application();
var document = new  Document();

document = application.Documents.Add(@"C:\Users\ISAAC B\Desktop\TECH HAVEN PROJECTS/template.docx");

application.Visible = true;

foreach (Field field in document.FormFields)
{
    if (field.Code.Text.Contains("Name"))
    {
        field.Select();
        application.Selection.TypeText("Tayo");
    }
}

document.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\ISAAC B\Desktop\TECH HAVEN PROJECTS/Project2017");

document.Close();
application.Quit();
```

Comment: You appear to be using form fields, not mail merge (a specific technology in Word), so I've corrected the title accordingly. Look at the document (or the template) in the Word application; double-click the form field and you should get a dialog box with options for the field. One of those options is the Name of the field. You can address any form field in the (protected!) document and write to it using document.FormFields("theName").Result = "Tayo"

Comment: Thank you @CindyMeister. Please i want to use mail merge. because what i wanted is to write into the word document  programatically

Comment: I think i found a solution to it. So i can input data and save it into a word document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Object oTrue = true;
        Object oFalse = false;
        Application oWord = new Application();
        Document oWordDoc = new Document();
      //  oWord.Visible = true;
        Object oTemplatePath = @"C:\Users\ISAAC B\Desktop\TECH HAVEN PROJECTS\Arup\template.docx";
        oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        foreach (Field myMergeField in oWordDoc.Fields)
        {
            Range rngFieldCode = myMergeField.Code;
            String fieldText = rngFieldCode.Text;
            if (fieldText.StartsWith(" MERGEFIELD"))
            {
                Int32 endMerge = fieldText.IndexOf("\\", StringComparison.Ordinal);
                Int32 fieldNameLength = fieldText.Length - endMerge;
                String fieldName = fieldText.Substring(11, endMerge - 11);
                fieldName = fieldName.Trim();
                if (fieldName == "Name")
                {
                    myMergeField.Select();
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText("Tayo Isaac Bakare");
                }
            }
        }
        oWordDoc.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\ISAAC B\Desktop\TECH HAVEN PROJECTS\Arup\Project2017.docx");
        oWordDoc.Close();
        oWord.Quit();
```